# Sort by columns

Tags: sort, columns, text-formatting

I need to sort a file by multiple columns.  There are 12 columns and I need to sort first by column 2, then 11, and lastly 3.  The third column should be in reverse order (highest to lowest values).  I also want to save the sorted columns to a new document.  This is the command I'm using but it's not working:

sort -k 2,2 Filename | sort -k 11,11 | sort -k 3,3 -r -o test_sorting.txt

What should I do differently?

Comment: Have you tried just using sort once?  Sort -k ... -k ... etc. Otherwise it's ignoring any previous sorting earlier in the pipe, maybe

Answer (score 3):

You can chain keys in the same command, it will sort in the order specified.

```
sort -o test_sorting.txt -k 2,2 -k 11,11 -k 3,3r Filename
```